# Getting Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move all the mails after removing the special characters in the filename to some destination based on the filename.
FOLDLIST is an array, where I'm having the condition variable and destination foldername.

```
    Set-Location 'C:\Users\abrahame\Desktop\Work\PSG Mail Movement\Mail'
    $DESLOC="c:\Temp\ua-closed bugs"
    $FOLDLIST = @(("UA", "CLOSE",  "ua-closed bugs"), ("VS", "CLOSE", "vs-closed-bugs"), ("CM", "CLOSED", "cm - closed-bugs"))
    gci | Foreach-object { $NEWN = $_.Name -replace '&',' ' -replace '_', ' ' -replace '#', ' ' -replace '!', ' '  -replace '@', ' '  -replace '$', ' '  -replace '%', ' '  -replace '^', ' '  -replace '&', ' '  -replace '\(', ' ' -replace '\)', ' '  -replace '\[', ' ' -replace '\]', ' ' -replace '\{', ' '  -replace '\}', ' ' -replace '\-', ' ';
            write-host $NEWN.Length
            if($NEWN.Length -gt  70){
                    $NEWN="$NEWN.Substring(1,70)"
                    $NEWN=$NEWN.msg


            }

            $FOLDLIST | ForEach-Object {
            $CXR=$_[0]
            $STAT=$_[1]

            if ($NEWN -match ("$CXR") -and $NEWN -match ("$STAT")){
            write-host $CXR -  $STAT
                    $DIR=$_[2]
                    $NEWN=$NEWN.trim()
                    $DPATH="$DESLOC\$DIR\$NEWN"
                    write-host $DPATH
                    mv $_.Name $DPATH
            }
            }

    }
```

I'm getting this error. Please advise where I did mistake..

```
    67
    UA - CLOSE
    c:\Temp\ua-closed bugs\ua-closed bugs\RE  CLOSE OA TICKET   10350   OA   UAT PHASE FOR HP FARES  1 .msg
    Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    At C:\Users\abrahame\Desktop\Work\PSG Mail Movement\mailmove_multdimentional.ps1:24 char:5
    +         mv <<<<  $_.Name $DPATH
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCom
       mand
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that $_.Name does not exist.

If I were you, I'd bring the script into the ISE and run it line for line till you get there then take a look at the value of $_

Comment: In my case, this was true and thus using conditional logic such as `If($var){$var | % {Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False}};`. So it'll only take this action is that `$var` is true and if it's not true or null, it'll still move on after the conditional logic or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

`$_` is the active object in the current pipeline.  You've started a new pipeline with `$FOLDLIST | ...` so `$_` represents the objects in that array that are passed down the pipeline. You should stash the FileInfo object from the first pipeline in a variable and then reference that variable later e.g.:

```
write-host $NEWN.Length
$file = $_
...
Move-Item $file.Name $DPATH
```

Comment: Keith, I'm doing the same as you advised.  $CXR=$_[0]
 $STAT=$_[1] and $DIR=$_[2] . I'm taking the information and storing in these variables and using that..

Comment: Thank you Very much.. It is because of first for loop. You are right.